# R script on microcomputer

Tags: r

I have a script in R that uses loess to find a curve of best fit for some data, integrates that curve and then does some simple arithmitic from there to come up with a number. It is for a testing unit which is handheld, and therefore I need to run it on a microcomputer. There are ones out there with Arm processors which will run linux (520MHz Low-power ARM processor, 128 MB of RAM).

My question is will this have enough power to do the calculations, and will R even run on a system like this?

Any suggestions or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: R runs under Linux (I'm guessing that was a typo?); there are binaries available for many common flavors, or you can build from source.  There's absolutely no way to tell how long your calculation will take, since you haven't provided estimates as to the size of the data, precision desired, etc.  Not to mention an estimate of the RAM available after your OS has grabbed its share.

Comment: FWIW: I'm not sure about contemporary memory requirements, but older versions of R presumably worked on machines with substantially less RAM - on par with the system you describe.  You might look up older code, to see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have compatible C and FORTRAN compilers as well as the GNU OS and Linux kernel to build R from sources. The lack of compatible compilers is likely to doom this strategy. I suspect you will have better success using for code from `loess` and `simpleLoess` as a template for a compiled version in C.

Comment: DWin, thanks for the response. Just a shot in the dark, but do you know if windows CE would have the C and FORTRAN drivers you mentioned?

Comment: I would have thought that to be even less promising. In searching hte r-help archives I found one posting form 2005 where R had been ported to a Debian-ARM set up but the ATLAS libraries were not working. Brian's post seems to be the avenue to explore further.

Comment: Well i guess realistically this is when i should write a mobile app that incorperates R...but considering my severe lack of mobile app experience maybe i will try to sway the cust towards a full blown laptop instead. I really didnt feel soldering together a charging circuit to support a battery powered board anyways. But if that fails, an ARM processor it is!

Answer (score 1):

As to your second question, R can be made to run on ARM processors.  See, for example, http://maemo.org/packages/view/r-base-core/ which is a port to Maemo which is an operating system on ARM processors for handheld devices.  It also can be compiled for Android: http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=getting-started:installation:android.

As @Carl said, the first question can't be answered without knowing more details.

Comment: Perfect those are great articles. I guess this is when my lack of experience with droid apps comes back to haunt me.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on [this](http://antipastohw.blogspot.com/2010/07/introducing-100-open-source-hwsw-r.html) post depicting an Open Source HW/SW R-Based Graphing Calculator based on [this](http://www.liquidware.com/shop/show/BB-C4/BeagleBoard+C4) motherboard!

HIH!

Comment: Thats awesome! At least now i know it is possible to run R on something like that. If it'll compile on a beagle board, i should not have any issues on an board running an Atom.